# Change the value of select attribute of xsl:for-each tag by javascript

Tags: javascript, xslt

I want to change value of select in xsl:for-each

```
<script>
var val = someValue() ://String
document.getElementById("test").select=val;
</script>
<body>
<xsl:for-each id="test" select="get from JS" >
.... 
.....
</xsl:for-each>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add more details to make your question easy to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to change the value of an attribute of a DOM node. 
You can use setAttribute("attribute", "value") to achieve that.

```
document.getElementById("test").setAttribute("select", val);
```

You may refer DOM API reference here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Comment: It's working for another dom elements, but not for xsl tag

Comment: @DnyaneshwarTaur - It won't work for the XSL attribute, because as Michael Kay explained in his answer, by the time the javascript runs, the XSLT will be long gone, and not accessible. The browser is executing the HTML after it has been generated by the XSLT. You should really edit your question to give details on how you are actually performing the XSLT transformation. Are you doing it on the server? Or on the front-end using javascript? Or are you simply using the xml-stylesheet directive in an XML file? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Typically when running XSLT in the browser, the XSLT code is first executed to generate the HTML page, and only when the HTML page has been generated are JS scripts within the page executed. By then it's too late to change the XSLT (it's already been executed).

Perhaps if you explain what you are actually trying to achieve then we can suggest an alternative approach.

You might like to take a look at Saxon-JS which provides a more dynamic way of exploiting XSLT in the browser, with more opportunity for the XSLT and Javascript code to work together.

Comment: actually I'm trying to fetch parameter value from url, and base on this value i want change value of 'select' attribute.

Comment: Url is domain.com/q=gulm (where gulm is value given by previous page ). I fetched this value by js method (someValue() in my sample code). Now I want to use for select Attribute